# MySQL Procedural Languages

Tags: mysql

SQL query: Documentation

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tree_add_root()
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
$max = SELECT MAX(`rht`) FROM trees;
INSERT INTO trees(`tree_id`, `name`, `label`, `description`, `lft`, `rht`, `lvl`) VALUES(1, 'Index', 'Index', '', 1,$max+1 , 0);
COMMENT;
END;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '= SELECT MAX(`rht`) FROM trees; INSERT INTO trees(`tree_id`,
>   `name`, `label`, `' at line 4

how can I solve this?

Comment: $max is a variable in which I store the maximum value of "rht"

Comment: I want to get max(`rht`) from trees and want to put the value in insert query. how can i do this?

Comment: try @max instead of $max

Comment: afterr using @max i have faced this problem 
 MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@max = SELECT MAX(`rht`) FROM trees;
INSERT INTO trees(`tree_id`, `name`, `labe' at line 5

Comment: "COMMENT;" you mean "COMMIT;" mate?

Answer (score 1):

```
Use This

CREATE PROCEDURE tree_add_root()
BEGIN
DECLARE v_max int(11);
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT MAX(`rht`) into v_max FROM trees;
INSERT INTO trees(`tree_id`, `name`, `label`, `description`, `lft`, `rht`, `lvl`) VALUES(1, 'Index', 'Index', '', 1,v_max+1 , 0);
COMMIT;
END;
```

Before using any variable in MySQL procedure, required to declare first using DECLARE keyword like above query, after start the body (BEGIN). using here v_max instead of $max.

Also COMMIT Keyword use instead of comment.

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment I made in your question..

..you can try this one, mate:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `tree_add_root`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `tree_add_root` ()
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;      
    SET @max = (SELECT MAX(`rht`) FROM trees);      
    INSERT INTO trees (`tree_id`, `name`, `label`, `description`, `lft`, `rht`, `lvl`)
    VALUES (1, 'Index', 'Index', '', 1, (@max + 1), 0);     
    COMMIT;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

So that whenever you call the function, all you need to execute is:

```
CALL tree_add_root();
```

I hope this one can help you, cheers!